# How do I split names with a regular expression?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to ruby and regular expressions and trying to figure out how to attack seperating the attached string of baseball players into  first/last name combinations.

This is a sample string:

```
"JohnnyCuetoJ.J.PutzBrianMcCann"
```

This is the desired output:

```
Johnny Cueto
J.J. Putz
Brian McCann
```

I have figured out how to separate by capital letters which gets me close, but the outlier names like `J.J.` and `McCann` mess that pattern up. Anyone have ideas on the best way to approach this?

Comment: It looks like your data is missing some separators, and you should look into why. Where is the data coming from? Are you scraping a web page?

Comment: How are you supposed to guess which names belong together to form a single person when they are mixed together like that? There are people in this world with everything from one to four or more name parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to do it in one single `gsub` than it gets a bit easier.

```
string = "JohnnyCuetoJ.J.PutzBrianMcCann"
string.gsub!(/([A-Z][^A-Z]+)/, '\1 ') # separate by capital letters
string.gsub!(/(\.) ([A-Z]\.)/, '\1\2') # paste together "J. J." -> "J.J."
string.gsub!(/Mc /, 'Mc') # Remove the space in "Mc "
string.strip # Remove the extra space after "Cann "
```

...and of course you can put this on a single line by chaining the `gsub` calls, but that will basically kill the readability of the code (but on the other hand, how readable is a block of regexen anyway?)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Frost. Conceptually speaking, since my universe of possible strings is going to be every player in the major leagues, do you think a regex is achievable that wouldnt need to have a specific player step such as what you did for McCann?

Comment: Also where can I learn about the syntax used in the replacement argument of the gsub method? Not sure what '\1 ' does.

Comment: Don't forget players with Irish names like O'Connor and O'Neill. I'm sure there are other special cases you will also need to handle.

Comment: WRT "McCann": that's actually a general rule which would also apply to McDonald, McKinley, etc.  So it's not name-specific.  But the code will never be fool-proof -- if you add an additional year's players your almost certain to break your algorithm because names are so diverse.

Comment: The escaped numbers in the replacement arguments matches the catching groups in the regexen, so that if I match `/(Mc) /` and replace it with `\1`, the result will be that I stripped the space after `"Mc"`. You might want to read up a bit on regex and grouping here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html. And as the others say, this method will not be fool-proof.

Comment: You should be able to address the O'Connor issue by changing the last of the gsub lines to `gsub!(/(Mc|O') /, '\1')`, btw.